# Line break before member variable if annotated

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, code-formatting

Using IntelliJ IDEA, is there a way to configure the Java Code Style to add a line break before annotated member variables (but not non-annotated member variables). Or, perhaps it's possible that *all* member variables would have a line break before them if *any* member variables were annotated (and had a line break before the annotation(s)).

For example ...

```java
// current / default -- hard to interpret at a glance
class Blah {
    private int id;
    @Required
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String firstName;
    @Required
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String lastName;
    private Instant birthDate;
    private String favoriteColor;
}
```

```java
// option 1: spaces before/after annotated members
class Blah {
    private int id;

    @Required
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @Required
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String lastName;

    private Instant birthDate;
    private String favoriteColor;
}
```

```java
// option 2: spaces before all members / annotated members if any is annotated
class Blah {
    private int id;

    @Required
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @Required
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String lastName;

    private Instant birthDate;

    private String favoriteColor;
}

class BlahWithoutAnnotations {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Instant birthDate;
    private String favoriteColor;
}
```

So, looking for a way to configure the Code Style to format things like Option 1 or 2. Preferably 2.

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please follow the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110857

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java` and within the Blank Lines tab find the option in the `Minimum Blank Lines` section labelled `Around field:` and change its value to `1`. This will give you option 2; I am unsure how to get your option 1 but I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I see that setting. However, note that option 2 only adds the line break if _any_ member has an annotation. See my example class `BlahWithoutAnnotations`.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm sorry I missed that. I'll do some more digging and update my answer should I find anything more relevant.